# iOS 16.0 or Higher Crash: UITableView Class - Internal Inconsistency Fatal Exception

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, mobile, ios16

I hope you're doing well. I wanted to bring up an issue I recently encountered in a live build. Some users have reported experiencing the following problem, primarily on devices with iOS version **16.0 or higher:**

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (3), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).

Crash was happening at below lines :

**tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)**
**tableView.reloadSections([sections], with: .automatic)**

I understand that using **tableView.reloadData()** would solve the crash, but this code has been working fine for the past six months. The sudden occurrence of this crash prompted me to seek assistance here to determine if anyone is aware of recent changes in the OS update or the UITableView class that could be causing this issue.

I have reviewed similar questions and have checked for common pitfalls like **beginUpdates** and **endUpdates** calls, but I'm keen to understand if any specific changes have been made to the recent OS update or the UITableView class that could be causing this problem.

These lines i have already in code and working fine till now and still i cant find crash in my device but other devices reported crash for this code :

**tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)**
**tableView.reloadSections([sections], with: .automatic)**

And this line solve the crash

**tableView.reloadData()**

Below is the code for sections array manage:

FRConfig is a class which contains all firebase remote config methods.

```
  static func fetchHomeSections(completion: @escaping (String?) -> ()){
        let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
        settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configSettings = settings
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch(withExpirationDuration: 0, completionHandler:   { status, error in
            if status == .success, error == nil{
                RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activate()
                if let val = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: RemoteConfigKey.home_sections.rawValue).stringValue {
                    completion(val)
                }
            }else{
                //here default array value we have in case of error and that we have set in string format
                completion(val)
            }
        })
    }

static func getHomeSectionsForFirebase(completion: @escaping (Data?,NoDataErrorCase) -> ()){
        FRConfig.fetchHomeSections { str in
            if let str = str {
                completion(Data(str.utf8),.none)
            }
        }
 }

func loadHomeSections()
{
       getHomeSectionsForFirebase { data,error  in
            if let data = data{
                do {
                    let objSection = try JSONDecoder().decode(HomeSectionModel.self, from: data)
                    if defaultsData.isFree(), let tmpSect = objSection.freeUserSection{
                        self.mainVC?.arrSection = tmpSect.sorted(by: {$0.index ?? 0 < $1.index ?? 0 })
                    }else if let tmpSect = objSection.registeredUserSection{
                        self.mainVC?.arrSection = tmpSect.sorted(by: {$0.index ?? 0 < $1.index ?? 0 })
                    }
                    self.manageHealthStatus() // Another api call
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.mainVC?.homeTableVw.reloadData() }
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
         }
    }
```

But unnecessarily reload entire table is not a good practise.

I would greatly appreciate any help in identifying the root cause of this issue.

Thank you all in advance for your assistance and support.

Comment: It seems more likely that an error in your code has surfaced with ios16. It could be timing related if there are asynchronous events involved.  [edit] your question and show the relevant code. It looks like the value returned by `numberOfSections` is changing without you telling the tableview that you have added a section.

Comment: Hey @Paulw11, unfortunately, I can't share the code due to its large size and confidentiality. However, the logic behind it is fetching section titles from Firebase Remote Config. Each section requires separate API calls, and cells are loaded accordingly, with different types of collection views (horizontal, vertical, etc.). I would reload the sections whenever an API response for a section came in. All API calls were made simultaneously, and the first response would trigger the section reload. Do you have any suggestions for a more efficient approach to handle this screen?

Comment: You can perhaps at least show your `numberOfSections` function, because that is almost certainly where your problem lies.  If it returns some array `count` then you need to make sure that the number of elements in that array can't change without you calling insert/remove sections.  When you get a new section you should dispatch onto the main queue a block that does - 1. `beginUpdates` 2. Appends the element to the array. 3. Calls `insertSections` 4. `endUpdates`. It is very important that you do not modify the sections array on any other queue except the main queue.

Comment: @Paulw11, Please review question i have modified it and added code for sections array manage

Comment: Ok, so if the number of elements in `self.mainVC?.arrSection` changes and you call `reloadRows` or `reloadSection` you will get a crash, because the table view doesn't expect the section count to change unless you have calls insert/delete section.